# How to expose SQL 2008 database to the world through the Internet?

Tags: sql-server, web-hosting

My web hosting provider allows me to setup an SQL Server 2008 database from their web pages and then provides with an address of the form "tcp:domain.bla.net" that I can use to connect from anywhere. I can even use SS Management Studio!

My question is, how can I expose my own database in that way from my own server? (assuming I already have a fixed IP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open port 1443 on your firewall and it should be accessible by IP.

Comment: Assuming the instance is listening on the default port, but yes.

Comment: 1433/1434: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Comment: Remus is correct as you need 1433 and 34

Answer (score 13):

Just a word of caution here: port 1433 (the default SQL Server port) is subject to frequent port scans and brute *sa* password attacks on the internet. Your instance will be discovered in a matter of hours and will be subject to several automated attacks per day (I'm not kidding). I would highly recommend:

1. Use a non default port
2. Harden your SQL Server instance. Make sure you have a very strong *sa* password, expire and rotate your password, disable non-used logins, use a non sysadmin login when connecting from internet, enforce the SSL encryption requirement on the server side.

Comment: Plus note that you do not expose the DATABASE but the SERVER INSTANCE - with all databases that it hosts. Isolating the databases in question may be advisable.